# Can I pass a CSV file as command line argument to <Loaddata> in Liquibase? If not, is there any other way to do it?

Tags: liquibase

is there a way to pass the TEST.csv value from the command line

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tb_mt_data_map;</sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
<loadData encoding="UTF-8"
          file= "TEST.csv"
          separator=";"
          quotchar="'"
          relativeToChangelogFile="true"
          tableName="tb_mt_data_map">
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to pass the TEST.csv value from the command line

You can use [Liquibase Property Substitution](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-property-substitution.html)

Liquibase allows dynamic substitution of properties in changelog files. We can configure multiple properties inside a file and then use them wherever required. You can configure "csvFileName" and then use it in changesets with syntax `${csvFileName}`.

You can either pass the property value from command line `-DcsvFileName=Test.csv` or you can configure it's value in liquibase.properties file.

```
csvFileName=Test.csv
```

Then you can use it in your changeset as follows:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tb_mt_data_map;</sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
<loadData encoding="UTF-8"
          file= "${csvFileName}"
          separator=";"
          quotchar="'"
          relativeToChangelogFile="true"
          tableName="tb_mt_data_map">
```

For more details on property substitution, have a look at my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982395/apply-migration-in-all-schema-that-i-have-using-liquibase/66985298#66985298)

Comment: sorry, I didn't get your doubt here. Are you saying you tried and it didn't work?

Comment: does main class is  need for  above command to  run

Comment: by `main class` what are you referring to? By using the above changeset and configuring the property in `liquibase.properties` file and running `liquibase update` from command line, it works for me.